# How to embed shell snippets in doxygen documentation

Tags: shell, syntax-highlighting, doxygen

When installing my package, the user should at some point type

```
./wand-new "`cat wandcfg_install.spell`"
```

Or whatever the configuration file is called. If I put this line inside \code ... \endcode, doxygen thinks it is C++ or... Anyway, the word "new" is treated as keyword. How do I avoid this is in a semantically correct way?

I think \verbatim is disqualified because it actually is code, right?

(I guess the answer is to poke that Dimitri should add support for more languages inside a code block like LaTeX listings package, or at least add an disableparse option to code in the meantime)

Comment: You can specify the language the code block is formatted in using `\code{LANGUAGE}`, in this case probably **.sh**. Verbatim would still likely work, it means simply print out the text section exactly as formatted inside the highlight box.

Comment: It does not help. So a bug that it does parse when it does not have the feature implemented? So I am forced to verbatim now

Comment: It would appear that `bash` isn't a supported Doxygen language (and the doc for `\code` states that the enclosed code must be to parse correctly), so no it isn't going to know how to parse that. It looks like `\code` simply ignores the language argument if it's not valid, in which case it falls back to the default which is to use the type of the source where the dox comment was found.

Comment: Indeed, in this case it should default to a dummy parser making it equivalent to verbatim

Answer (score 1):

Doxygen, as of July 2017, does not officially support documenting Shell/Bash scripting language, not even as an [extension](http://www.doxygen.nl/helpers.html). There is an unofficial filter called [bash-doxygen](https://github.com/Anvil/bash-doxygen). Simple to setup: only one file download and three flags adjustments:

- Edit the `Doxyfile` to map shell files to C parser: `EXTENSION_MAPPING = sh=C`
- Set your shell script file names pattern as Doxygen inputs, like
  e.g.: `FILE_PATTERNS = *.sh`
- Mention `doxygen-bash.sed` in either the `INTPUT_FILTER` or the
  `FILTER_PATTERN` directive of your Doxyfile. If `doxygen-bash.sed` is in
  your `$PATH`, then you can just invoke it as is, else use `sed -n -f /path/to/doxygen-bash.sed --`.

Please note that since it uses C language parsing, some limitations apply, as stated in the main *README* page of [bash-doxygen](https://github.com/Anvil/bash-doxygen), one of them, at least in my tests, that the `\code {.sh}` recognises shell syntax, but all lines in the code block begin with an asterisk (`*`), apparently as a side-effect of requiring that all Doxygen doc sections have lines starting with double-hashes (`##`).

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: This answer provides a partial solution to @user877329 's need for shell code snippets in `\code {.sh}` blocks.

Comment: \code{.unparsed} might give some answers also the \snippet command may help